# Java incomparable types

Tags: java, object

I'm not that experienced with java and I'm having a big problem here. Basically, what I have to do is create a Tic Tac Toe. So I at a point in my code, create 9 cells for the game from the file Cell.java using the constructor that is within it. These cells's type is Cell, the object. What I want to do with them so that the program can progress is to compare the values that are in EACH cell with a given value, say 1 for X or 2 for O so I can know who has won, where to put each move etc. . The problem I encounter is that I dont know how to get the content of each cell, because if I dont get it the compiler throws me an error about incomparable types, Cell and int. Is there a way to get the content of each individual cell?

The Cell constructor:

```
public Cell(int rows, int cols){
        row = rows;
        col = cols;
    }
```

The contructor I use to create the Cells:

```
Cell[][] cells = new Cell[rows][cols];
    public Board(){

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                cells[rows][cols] = new Cell(rows, cols);
            }
        }
    }
```

What doesn't work is when I try to make this comparison for example:

```
if(cells[currRow][0] == Player && cells[currRow][1] == Player && cells[currRow][2] == Player)
```

Comment: why don't use array index as your row/col index? Just store a String(O or X) in the cell.

Comment: Could you add the code that is causing your problem? Right now you've shown us what's working so far instead of what you're trying to do which isn't working.

Comment: @user3083578 use `.equals()` to compare object, not `==`

Comment: What is `Player` in this context?  Maybe you could post ALL of your code, rather than a few lines at a time.

Comment: You first have to define a variable in Cell to store the value. Then as game progress you have to set the value of the Cell. You can then compare this value.

Comment: @RafaEl So basically I just replace all of the == with .equals() and now all the errors are gone. But the program wont run.It says no class def found error

Comment: Post the stack trace.i.e, the error that you are getting.
Meanwhile have a look at this 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 0):

You need a add a private field to the Cell class, and then methods to return the field and to set the field:

```
public class Cell {
    private int value;
    private int col;
    private int row;

    public Cell(int rows, int cols) {
        value = 0;
        row = rows;
        col = cols;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public int getRow() ...
    public int getCol() ...
}
```

This way you can just make checks using Cell.getValue()

Comment: Oh he updated his question, I'll get on adapting this

Comment: Maybe an `Enum` with the values X, O and BLANK would be a good candidate for the type of `value`.

Comment: I know that a solution that would surely work is using an enum but enums aren't in what I have been taught since this day.

Comment: @DavidWallace an Enum would be perfect, but I'll leave it as-is since he doesn't want to use them.